# Is is possible to create ER Diagram in SQL Developer using Synonyms instead of Tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, erd

I have tried using the following method to create an ER diagram

View → Data Modeler → Browser and then creating a new relational model. In that we can create and drag the tables and the ER diagram is generated. But I observed that we cannot drag synonyms in the same way to generate ER diagram.
Is there any way to get ER diagrams of synonyms?

Comment: Why do you want to use synonyms?

Comment: the requirement is like that, there are all synonyms in the source db..

Comment: @harry synonyms are just shortcuts or aliases for existing objects, there is no referential integrity tied to a synonym - you would go after the underlying views and tables instead

Comment: @thatjeffsmith so what you are saying that it is not possible using Synonyms, right?

Comment: @harry yes that is correct...you could create a model with just synonyms but you'd have no diagram

Comment: @thatjeffsmith got it! thank you!